# exporting query result to excel

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to execute the below sql but I am getting "`Invalid object name '.Sheet1$'.`"

```
INSERT INTO OPENDATASOURCE 
    ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Database=c:\test.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')..[Sheet1$])
    SELECT col1 FROM table;
```

its in mssql 2005.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `xp_cmdshell` enabled you can do this to export to delimited text file, which will open perfect in Excel.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S [SERVERNAME] -d [DBNAME] -o "C:\Output.txt" -s "," -U "[USERNAME]" -P "[PASWORD]" -Q "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table"';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/b6406f4a-f4b0-439b-bded-861de2d5a3c3/) (and a few other samples Google found for me), you need three dots before the table: 8.0)...[Sheet1$]. (Don't ask me why).

Added: [The German translation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms179856.aspx) of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276845%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) provides a complete example of Excel access:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\DataFolder\Documents\TestExcel.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] ;
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I hesitate/have no rights to ask - but did you try one dot?